# Is there a good library in CPAN for filtering out cross-site scripting (XSS)?

Tags: perl, security, xss

Is there a good library in CPAN for filtering out an textfield for all the bad things, like xss?

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [Filtering JavaScript out of HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858773/filtering-javascript-out-of-html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first step should always be to search and browse through the results. It looks like there are [lots of potential hits](http://search.cpan.org/search?mode=all&query=xss). When I'm looking for something new, I browse through search results and check the docs of modules to see how clear they are and how well built the API is. I also look for reviews (some have, some don't - it's often random) and check bugs. It gives me a sense of what I'm dealing with.

If your question is "Which of these various options is best?", then I'm afraid I don't know in this case. (My initial answer may have been too general.)

Two good places to start a search of CPAN:

- [Search CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/)
- [Kobes' search](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/)

Answer (score 0):

At the base level you want [HTML::Entities](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities), but which escape you chose depends on where in the DOM you're using the values. It won't help at all to html entity encode a user input if you stick it inside a `<script>` tag, for example.

It's pretty likely that you're using some kind of template to generate the html, so it should have a method to escape the content, `HTML::Mason` has `<% $thing |h %>`, `Template::Toolkit` has `[% thing | html %]`... but if you're just doing it in your own code you'll need to call `encode_entities` yourself.